# Is it undesirable to store pointers in multiple containers with different access methods?

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am currently working on making a node graph to store tile/object data for a 2D game that I am working on. Essentially it's a map of hexagon tiles with objects on each tile.

My current setup looks basically like this:

```
class HexCell {
public:
    HexCell* GetNeighbor(int dir) { return neighbors[dir]; };
private:
    HexCell* neighbors[6];
    // (x, y) position
    // Contents of cell
};

class HexGraph {
public:
    HexCell* GetCellByIndex(int index) { return cells[index]; };
    vector<HexCell*> GetCellsByGridIndex(int x, int y) { return grid[x][y]; };
private:
    vector<HexCell*> cells;
    vector< vector< vector <HexCell*> > > grid;
};
```

So currently there are 3 ways to access HexCells:

1. Random Access through `cells[]` (useful for iterating the whole list)
2. Looking up a subset of the cells with `grid[x][y]` (useful for rendering)
3. Cell-level traversal of the graph nodes (useful for game logic)

My question then is: **Is it a terrible waste of memory to store 8 pointers for each object (one in `cells` one in `grid` and up to six as neighbors of other cells)?**

Is there a better/more common way to do this, or is it an acceptable system in order to have different access methods for different uses?

Comment: Storing (handles to) the same information in different data structures in order to support different lookup strategies is perfectly alright as long as the gain in lookup speed justifies the loss of space. But on a modern computer, it's going to take an awful lot of pointers to make a noticeable dent in your RAM.

Comment: Which of course doesn't necessarily imply that your specific structures are justified by your specific use cases. :)

Comment: I guess the question becomes then "when is it justified?" As an amateur programmer I sometimes don't have a point of reference for what is too much space or what is too slow.

Answer (score 1):

Given a hex map is just a 2D grid with straight columns and wavy rows, I'd recommend storing your map data as a 2D array of HexCells. You'll be able to determine based on the X index whether the column of hex cells is even or odd to determine if it is one of the shifted down hex tiles

Here is a rough representation of the hex cells and their corresponding x,y indexes in a 10x4 array where X%2==1 are the columns that are shifted down by 1/2 of a hex cell height

```
0,0     2,0     4,0     6,0     8,0
    1,0     3,0     5,0     7,0     9,0
0,1     2,1     4,1     6,1     8,1
    1,1     3,1     5,1     7,1     9,1
0,2     2,2     4,2     6,2     8,2
    1,2     3,2     5,2     7,2     9,2
0,3     2,3     4,3     6,3     8,3
    1,3     3,3     5,3     7,3     9,3
```

Using this method you can write logic to determine the 6 neighbors of X,Y pretty trivially without storing extra info in each hex cell

Comment: Well, in my case it does happen to be hexagons (at the moment) but I may want to use a graph in the future which isn't strictly 6 edges to a node. My question was more towards the Smaller Storage vs. More Flexibility issue in general.

Comment: Well if all of your tiles are the same, there's only 3 shapes that allow for creating a continuous surface, that's parallelograms  (rectangles, squares, diamonds), triangles, and hexagons. If you want the flexibility, I'd go with pointers but it's more straightforward to use the grid method and you can trivially replace tiles without having to initialize all of the neighbor pointers on that tile and it's neighbors